# How do I fixed conflict namespace named "Shared" in asp.net core _imports.razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

1. Class library: `Shared`
2. Namespace: `@using Shared.Extensions`

> Error: CS0234
> The type or namespace name 'Extensions' does not exist in the namespace 'Web.Areas.User.Views.Shared' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
> Error location: _Imports.razor

Comment: Hi @Saman Bahrekazemi, how is your project structure like? Do you have two project and each project contains _Imports.razor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just encountered this same problem. It appears when the razor file is compiled and you have an expression somewhere on the page/component, it is generating 'using' statements and declaring a variable to hold the result of the expression, without checking if there are namespace conflicts. This could be solved in the generator by prefixing the namespace with `global::`, but I can't see that happening any time soon.

My current setup:

- Foo.sln

  - Client.csproj
  - Server.csproj
  - Shared.csproj

You need to prefix all the projects with a name so it doesn't conflict with Razor's default names:

- Foo.sln

  - Foo.Client.csproj
  - Foo.Server.csproj
  - Foo.Shared.csproj

To be honest, it's probably a good idea to fully qualify the projects anyway.